# cannot access child element - jquery

Tags: jquery, html, function, hover, children

I have a HTML like

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">
        something
    </div>

    <div class="c">
        <div class="subC">
            i want to access
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and jquery like

```
$('.a').hover(function(){
    $(this).children('.subC').fadeOut();
})
```

I Want to access the class "subC" but above is not working.

i also tried

```
$('.a').hover(function(){
    $(this).children('.c .subC').fadeOut();
})
```

but this too is not working !

Whats the solution to this problem ! am i doing anything wrong ? please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`children` only goes one level deep. Try `find()` instead.

http://api.jquery.com/children/

Answer (score 1):

When inside a jQuery closure, `this` refers to the jQuery object returned by the previous jQuery operation:

```
$('.a').hover(function() {
    // 'this' is a jQuery object containing the result of $('.a')
})
```

Use `this` within the closure to set the scope for querying inside the current jQuery object:

```
$('.a').hover(function() {
    $('.subC', this).fadeOut();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.find('selector')` to find deep children

Answer (score 0):

As Rob says, use `.find` to find deep elements.

```
$('.a').hover(function()
    {
        $(this).find('.c .subC').fadeOut();
    });
```

if you want to use `.children`, write

```
$('.a').hover(function(){
    $(this).children('.c').children('.subC').fadeOut();
})
```